# Google token life time for GoogleSignInApi

Tags: android, google-api-client, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

Is it possible to increate token life time or update the token without a user interaction?

```
GoogleSignInResult result
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            email = acct.getEmail();
            idToken = acct.getIdToken();
```

This code gives me a token whose lifetime is 1 hour.
What is the best way to force update token?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, right now, Google issues 1hr long id token. If you want to use the ID token as identity assertion for your session management, then you can simply use silentSignIn ([Javadoc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi.html#silentSignIn(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient))), which doesn't involve any user interaction. If your old token hasn't expired yet, you will get the (cached) version back (OptionalPendingResult returned will have isDone()==true); if it expired already, you will get a refreshed one (but it will take a little longer and thus OptionalPendingResult isDone() will be false).

Also, depending on whether you call silentSignIn on UI thread or worker thread. If you call it on worker thread, take a look at this post with blockingConnect() + await() which simplifies the code a lot:
[Silent sign in to retrieve token with GoogleApiClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900956/silent-sign-in-to-retreive-token-with-googleapiclient/35075234#35075234)