# How to refresh ID token after it expires when integrating Google sign-in on Android?

Tags: android, google-signin

I've followed the guides on https://developers.google.com/ and I can get the Google ID token of the signed in user after the user signed in. But I noticed that the token will expire in 1 hour. I cannot find any official reference that tells me how to deal with expired Google ID token, so I can only ask the user to click the Google sign-in button again.

How can I refresh a valid Google ID token after the old one expires, without bothering user to manually sign in again and again?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Google ID tokens are issued for one hour validity and will expire, you can simply use [silentSignIn](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInApi.html#silentSignIn(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) in your app to get a new one without any user interaction. If your existing token hasn't expired yet, you will get the (cached) version back (`OptionalPendingResult` returned will have `isDone() == true`); if it expired already, you will get a refreshed one (but it will take a little longer and thus `OptionalPendingResult isDone()` will be `false`).

Here is [sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java#L85) (UI thread, see note below about a worker thread):

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
...

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);  // result.getSignInAccount().getIdToken(), etc.
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);  // result.getSignInAccount().getIdToken(), etc.
            }
        });
    }
```

Keep in mind whether you call `silentSignIn` on a UI thread or worker thread. If you call it on worker thread, take a look at this post with `blockingConnect()` + `await()` which simplifies the code a lot:
[Silent sign in to retrieve token with GoogleApiClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900956/silent-sign-in-to-retreive-token-with-googleapiclient/35075234#35075234)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem while trying to use the Google Photos Java API along with Google Sign In in an Android app. [Here is the problem I was facing](https://github.com/google/java-photoslibrary/issues/48). I essentially solved it by periodically fetching a new instance of `PhotosLibraryClient`, which itself fetches a new `GoogleAccountCredential` in the process. But I did have to be careful to properly tear down the existing `PhotosLibraryClient` before creating a new one:

```
    var lastGooglePhotosClientRefreshTimestamp = 0L

    fun createGooglePhotosClient(token: String): PhotosLibraryClient? {
        return try {
            App.googlePhotosClient?.let { client ->
                if (!client.isShutdown) {
                    client.shutdownNow()
                    client.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    client.close()
                }
            }
            val settings = PhotosLibrarySettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(
                FixedCredentialsProvider.create(getUserCredentials(token))).build()
            val photosLibraryClient = PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(settings)
            if (photosLibraryClient == null) {
                logMessage(TAG, "Google Photos library client could not be fetched.")
            } else {
                App.googlePhotosClient = photosLibraryClient
                lastGooglePhotosClientRefreshTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
            }
            return photosLibraryClient
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            logMessage(TAG, throwable.stackTraceToString())
            null
        }
    }

    private fun getUserCredentials(token: String): UserCredentials {
        val accessToken = AccessToken(token, null)
        return UserCredentials.newBuilder()
            .setClientId(App.appContext.getString(R.string.google_client_id))
            .setClientSecret(App.appContext.getString(R.string.google_client_secret))
            .setAccessToken(accessToken)
            .build()
    }


    // Call this method at or near the time of credential expiration 
    // to avoid an UnauthenticatedException. The server will only
    // grant you a new credential in such a circumstance
    // (otherwise it will return the same credential).
    suspend fun refreshGooglePhotosClient() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            if (App.googleSignInAccount == null) return@withContext
            val credential = getGoogleAccountCredential(App.googleSignInAccount!!, true, false)
            try {
                val token = credential.token
                createGooglePhotosClient(token)
            } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
                logMessage(TAG, "Error while calling refreshGooglePhotosClient(): ${throwable.stackTraceToString()}")
            }
        }
    }


// Fetch a GoogleSignInClient with all the required Scopes requested.
fun getGoogleSignInClient(activity: Activity, needsPhotosScope: Boolean, needsDriveScope: Boolean): GoogleSignInClient {
    val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions
        .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestServerAuthCode(App.appContext.getString(R.string.google_client_id), true)
        .requestEmail()
    val scopes = getRequiredGoogleServiceScopes(needsPhotosScope, needsDriveScope)
    when (scopes.size) {
        0 -> throw RuntimeException("Attempting to use Google Sign-In without requesting any Scopes.")
        1 -> signInOptions.requestScopes(scopes[0])
        2 -> signInOptions.requestScopes(scopes[0], scopes[1])
    }
    return GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, signInOptions.build())
}


fun getGoogleAccountCredential(googleSignInAccount: GoogleSignInAccount, needsPhotosScope: Boolean,
                               needsDriveScope: Boolean): GoogleAccountCredential {

    // Create list of Scopes in String form.
    val scopeStringList = getRequiredGoogleServiceScopes(needsPhotosScope, needsDriveScope).map { it.scopeUri }

    val credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(App.appContext, scopeStringList)
    credential.selectedAccount = googleSignInAccount.account
    return credential
}


// Fetch a List of Scopes that match the requirements based on the user's current search criteria.
fun getRequiredGoogleServiceScopes(needsPhotosScope: Boolean, needsDriveScope: Boolean): List<Scope> {
    val scopes = mutableListOf<Scope>()
    if (needsPhotosScope) scopes.add(Scope(googlePhotosScope))
    if (needsDriveScope) scopes.add(Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
    return scopes
}
```