# Authenticate with backend w/o user intervention (using the new Sign-in APIs)

Tags: android, google-signin, google-authentication, google-api-nodejs-client

We're currently able to authenticate requests between our Android client and server using a [deprecated approach](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/v1/backend-auth):

```
String scope = "audience:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID;
String account = getAnyGoogleAccountFromDevice();
String idToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, account, scope);
```

On the server side we validate the `idToken` using Google's certificates and verify the audience is our client.

This works well, but it seems Google has deprecated this approach and wants developers to switch to the new Sign-in APIs from PlayServices 8.3+:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/11/improvements-to-sign-in-with-google.html 
https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/moving-to-google-sign-in-for-a-better-user-experience-and-higher-conversion-rates.html

But the new docs approach, explained [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) and [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/migration-guide), doesn't allow use of some Google account we give it, but instead requires the user to sign-in to the app.
We want to have a **transparent way of authenticating with the backend, without any user intervention or UI**, we don't need the user's name/email/profile information, just require some token to validate the requests are coming from our own client.

Is there a way to do that using the new Google Sign-in APIs?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38750275/5001016

Comment: thanks, but that only works after the user signed in to the app (with a UI), I want to authenticate calls without any user intervention

Comment: do you know the user's email address beforehand?

Comment: yes, I can get the user's email

Comment: OK, in that case, try setting the email address with .setAccountName() when building the GoogleSignInOptions and GoogleApiClient using the new API and then call silentSignIn() and you should be able to get the token without UI

Comment: WOW, that worked! Thanks @StevenSoneff would you like to make that into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: OK, added and re-used your code, that looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know the user's email address you can refresh the ID token with the following:

```
// Run on a non-UI thread

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .setAccountName(emailAddress)
    .requestIdToken(SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
    .build();

GoogleApiClient client = new Builder(context)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .build();

ConnectionResult conn = client.blockingConnect();
if (!conn.isSuccess()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't connect GoogleApiClient");
    return;
}

GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(client).await();
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
Log.d(TAG, "ID Token: " + acct.getIdToken());

client.disconnect();
```

Comment: hey steven, I have a little follow up question, I basically have a singleton class that all activities/services in the app use, that singleton class gets the IdToken then makes a server call. So the app might be calling getIdToken many times, do I have to keep connecting my GoogleApiClient, calling silentSignIn, and then disconnecting whenever I need to make a server call? Should I keep the client connected at all times? can I call silentSignIn without first connecting the client?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Steven's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051608/authenticate-with-backend-w-o-user-intervention-using-the-new-sign-in-apis?noredirect=1#comment79461070_46051608), I was able to make `silentSignIn` work without user intervention, here's the code:

```
// Needs to be running on a non-UI thread

String account = getAnyGoogleAccountFromDevice();

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .setAccountName(account)
    .requestIdToken(SERVER_CLIENT_ID)
    .build();

GoogleApiClient client = new Builder(context)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .build();

ConnectionResult conn = client.blockingConnect();
if (!conn.isSuccess()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't connect GoogleApiClient");
    return;
}

GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(client).await();
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
Log.d(TAG, "ID Token: " + acct.getIdToken());

client.disconnect();
```