# How to get Access token(or GoogleSignInAccount) from GoogleApiClient?

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-api-java-client

I have to use google oauth to call a third party API from an Android app. At the very first time, I make the user sign in with their google account and get `GoogleSignInAccount` in `onActivityResult`. With that I get the access token for API call.

In the subsequent activity starts, I get my `GoogleApiClient` connected during the activity. So, no need to make the user sign in again. But how to get the access token or `GoogleSignInAccount` in these later cases, from the `GoogleApiClient`? Without any UI action, fully in the background? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Got my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900956/silent-sign-in-to-retrieve-token-with-googleapiclient